# Need newly created files to inherit ownership

Tags: rhel, acl, wordpress

I have set up a Wordpress Server for my developers and it is working.  However now when we copy over files to the /usr/share/nginx/html folder I am having permissions issues.  I will try explain this as easy as I can.

Here are the permissions on the folder:

drwxrwsr-x+ 9 **nginx wpress** 4096 Jun 16 08:41 html

As you can see the owner is 'nginx' and group is 'wpress'.
I did set up a ACL on this folder for a remote developer but that is not an issue.

My problem is that when my developer copies over files to this folder --> /usr/share/nginx/html it will not inherit the owner nginx.  It will look similar to this:

-rw-r--r--   1 **pbrod  wpress**       0 Jun 16 08:14 file1

How I would want it to look is as follows:

-rw-r--r--   1 **nginx  wpress**       0 Jun 16 08:14 file1

I want the files that are copied in or created to inherit the owner and group.  When I set up the permissions I did a 2775 on the folder so it would inherit group ownership.  The problem is that I need files created or copied into this folder to inherit the owner, which is **nginx**.

I am thinking I can do this via SETFACL but not 100% sure how to do it as anything I tried does not seem to work.